# How to troubleshoot xarray.open_rasterio parsing?

Tags: python, python-xarray, datashader

I want to rasterize smaller shades of high-resolution GeoTIFFs. `xarray.open_rasterio` seemed the right tool to get what `datashader.transfer_functions.shade` would need. However, the returned DataArray also has a band, which trips up `shade`. Several questions arise:

1. Should `xarray.open_rasterio` return the values currently in "band"
   simply as the values in the array?
2. How can one check whether the
   GeoTIFF looks like what `xarray.open_rasterio` expects?
3. Would any
   argument of `xarray.open_rasterio` allow the specification of "band"
   as the "value"?
4. Or should `xarray.open_rasterio` simply reorder or relabel the coordinates in a way such that "band" is the third one (after "x" and "y")?
5. Or if `xarray.open_rasterio` parsed this GeoTIFF
   correctly, could one call `shade` in a way it does not confuse this
   2D array with a 3D array?

MRE: Use a GeoTIFF from Facebook's high-resolution population maps, for instance, from [here](https://data.humdata.org/dataset/hungary-high-resolution-population-density-maps-demographic-estimates). The code below could put this on a 800x800 map. Instead, after I finally understood why `shade` complained it had only (the default) 22 colors in its `color_key` argument while it was trying to color 800 categories, I understood the `y` coordinate is understood by `shade` to be the value. I show the array below.

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.mask import mask
import os
import datashader as ds
from datashader import transfer_functions as tf
import xarray as xr
from matplotlib.cm import viridis

data_path = 'SOME_PATH/'
file_name = 'HUN_women_of_reproductive_age_15_49.tif'  # reproductive women, e.g.
file_path = os.path.join(data_path, file_name)

da = xr.open_rasterio(file_path)

cvs = ds.Canvas(plot_width=800, plot_height=800)

img = tf.shade(cvs.raster(da), cmap=viridis)
```

This fails because the `da` array looks like this:

```
<xarray.DataArray (band: 1, y: 10240, x: 24320)> array([[[nan, nan, ..., nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, ..., nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, ..., nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, ..., nan, nan]]]) Coordinates:   * band     (band) int64 1   * y        (y) float64 48.59 48.59 48.59 48.59 ... 45.75
45.75 45.75 45.75   * x        (x) float64 16.13 16.14 16.14 16.14 ... 22.89 22.89 22.89 22.89 Attributes:
    transform:      (0.000277777777778, 0.0, 16.13486111111111, 0.0, -0.00027...
    crs:            +init=epsg:4326
    res:            (0.000277777777778, 0.000277777777778)
    is_tiled:       1
    nodatavals:     (nan,)
    scales:         (1.0,)
    offsets:        (0.0,)
    descriptions:   ('Population Count',)
    AREA_OR_POINT:  Area
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cvs.raster() accepts a `layer` argument to specify which of the provided bands you want to rasterize; maybe that will help?

```
img = tf.shade(cvs.raster(da,layer=1), cmap=viridis)
```

In any case, note that datashader.transfer_functions.shade does not rasterize its input; that's done by a call to Canvas (specifically cvs.raster, here).  shade just converts an already rasterized array into colored pixels.

Comment: `img = tf.shade(cvs.raster(da,layer=1), cmap=viridis)` works beautifully, thanks. I'm happy to accept an answer if you write it up.